# No pppoe-server in Fedora 14?

Tags: linux, fedora

```
$ yum list | grep -i ppp
ppp.i686                                   2.4.5-12.fc14                @updates
rp-pppoe.i686                              3.10-6.fc12                  @fedora/$releasever
ppp-devel.i686                             2.4.5-12.fc14                updates 
$
```

There isn't any pppoe server in Fedora 14?? Wow! Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, rp-pppoe package includes quite capable pppoe server:

```
[kuba@bomba ~]$ wget -q http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/linux/releases/14/Everything/i386/os/Packages/rp-pppoe-3.10-6.fc12.i686.rpm
[kuba@bomba ~]$ rpm -qlp rp-pppoe-3.10-6.fc12.i686.rpm
/etc/ppp/firewall-masq
/etc/ppp/firewall-standalone
/etc/ppp/pppoe-server-options
/etc/rc.d/init.d/pppoe-server
/sbin/pppoe
/sbin/pppoe-connect
/sbin/pppoe-relay
/sbin/pppoe-server
/sbin/pppoe-setup
/sbin/pppoe-sniff
/sbin/pppoe-start
/sbin/pppoe-status
/sbin/pppoe-stop
/usr/sbin/adsl-start
/usr/sbin/adsl-stop
/usr/sbin/pppoe
/usr/sbin/pppoe-connect
/usr/sbin/pppoe-relay
/usr/sbin/pppoe-server
/usr/sbin/pppoe-setup
/usr/sbin/pppoe-sniff
/usr/sbin/pppoe-start
/usr/sbin/pppoe-status
/usr/sbin/pppoe-stop
/usr/share/doc/rp-pppoe-3.10
/usr/share/doc/rp-pppoe-3.10/LICENSE
/usr/share/doc/rp-pppoe-3.10/configs
/usr/share/doc/rp-pppoe-3.10/configs/firewall-masq
/usr/share/doc/rp-pppoe-3.10/configs/firewall-standalone
/usr/share/doc/rp-pppoe-3.10/configs/pap-secrets
/usr/share/doc/rp-pppoe-3.10/configs/pppoe-server-options
/usr/share/doc/rp-pppoe-3.10/configs/pppoe.conf
/usr/share/doc/rp-pppoe-3.10/pppoe-connect
/usr/share/doc/rp-pppoe-3.10/pppoe-init
/usr/share/doc/rp-pppoe-3.10/pppoe-setup
/usr/share/doc/rp-pppoe-3.10/pppoe-start
/usr/share/doc/rp-pppoe-3.10/pppoe-status
/usr/share/doc/rp-pppoe-3.10/pppoe-stop
/usr/share/man/man5/pppoe.conf.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/pppoe-connect.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/pppoe-relay.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/pppoe-server.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/pppoe-setup.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/pppoe-sniff.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/pppoe-start.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/pppoe-status.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/pppoe-stop.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/pppoe.8.gz
```

It installs pppd as a dependency too.

Answer (score 0):

Support for pppoe is included in NetworkManager